# Do I need one ‘that’ or two in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, optional-that

> You need something to look forward to. To light up your heart. To
>   forget that you’re walking in the dark. **Sure, sometimes you’ll
>   discover (that) that *something* doesn’t exist.** But so what? That
>   light already helped you to get through the day."

Do I need one ‘that’ or two in the sentence above? Why or why not?

Comment: You accepted an answer which explained whether you needed one or two _that_ words.  If you would also like to know whether alternative forms exist, which avoid using a double ‘that’, then you may be interested in reading some answers here:  [Is there a way to avoid saying 'that that'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/81843/50680)

Comment: With reference to @can-ned_food's comment: "... that *this* something" works here.

Comment: Here's a [related post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem) on EL&U.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your sentence you need a double *that* to make the meaning clear.

Note first that the word *that* is often elided without impacting on the meaning, so that:

> > You'll discover that something doesn't exist

becomes:

> > You'll discover something doesn't exist

However, if you elide the second *that* in your sentence, you do change the meaning. At present your sentence is saying:

> > ...you'll discover that *the particular* something concerned doesn't exist.

If you leave out the second that, the meaning changes to:

> > ...you'll discover that something doesn't exist.

This second sentence fails to clarify *which* something you are referring to.

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-that/

Comment: +1 We posted within about a minute of each other but yours came out first :) . My answer says pretty much the same thing, so I'm deleting mine in favour of yours.

Comment: @Lawrence Your'e a gentleman. I shall follow your example if the situation is ever reversed.