# Why are there two "thats" one after the other in this native English film?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

This is from a native English film [Modern Family](https://youtu.be/EOqiYBHLFEc?t=431) (see: 7:08-7:13)

**"Listen. I know I haven't been much help today. That that whole Jerry and Judy thing, it really hit me hard."**

I did not understand why there are two **"thats"** one after the other.

Actually, the film sounds like the first **"that"** belongs to the preceding sentence, (I know I haven't been much help today that.), but then it does not make sense, and also the subtitles show it as part of the second sentence, however, in that case two **"thats"** at the beginning of the sentence seems unusual.

Either way, I feel something is wrong there, but since the film is native English, I wanted to ask, maybe there is something else which I might be missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Repetition is common in speech when you're struggling to think of something or to form your ideas. Are you sure they're not just doing that? There are many cases in English when "that that" is grammatical - see e.g. [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81843/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-saying-that-that) - but that may not be the case here. Although maybe they have omitted some of "**The reason is** that that whole Jerry and Judy thing...", with the first "that" a conjunction introducing the clause and the second a demonstrative pronoun. but we can't know for sure.

Comment: (Also note that *Modern Family* is a contemporary American TV series not a film.)

Comment: @StuartF, Yes I have checked it. He is not just doing that. He is not saying it because he is thinking of something. He says both "thats" differently with a change in intonation. He says the first one as part of the first sentence. And then some time passes and then he starts another sentence. But interestingly, the subtitles show both "thats" as part of the second sentence. I can't be absolutely sure.

Comment: @yunus He is just pausing to collect his thoughts before starting the sentence over again. He is not starting a sentence with "that that", he is starting a sentence beginning with "that" twice.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Yes he's saying "That [*pause to think ... begin sentence again*] that [*continue with sentence*]"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise. The actor/character is known for his tics, and mild form of stuttering. That someone stutters or repeats a word twice is common in speech throughout the world.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/198917/64632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's just stumbling over his words and pausing briefly while he collects his thoughts, and then he repeats the **that**.  It isn't an issue of grammar.  It would be better transcribed as

> That - that whole Jerry and Judy thing, it really hit me hard.

Comment: I would say that this is a form of 'stammering', which people can do at times of stress. Father: What did that boy do? Little boy: He - he -he hit me!